# Issue not marked as finished in Gitlab iteration

Tags: gitlab, iteration, issue-tracking, burndowncharts

I am working in Gitlab and are running Sprints with iterations. I want to use the burndown chart for this but **none** of the issues attached to a closed iteration are marked as finished.

However the issues are all marked as closed in the table below. I do not understand how I can get me issues to be listed as completed so that the burndown charts won't always show 0% complete, which removes the need for iterations basically to me.